# Undefined variable warning from echoing a string

Tags: php

A bit of an unusual one this, and it has me a bit stumped. I have a php script that sits on a server. I have a local php script that calls that script. I log in to it via simple http authentication. There's nothing special about it, and everything works as it should, except that in my server script, I echo some text, like so;

```
echo "I WAS ABOUT TO RUN A RETAIL STOCK UPDATE AND YOU STOPPED ME.<br>";
```

Which because I am running this server script via my local script, I get an output of this;

```
Notice: Undefined variable: I WAS ABOUT TO RUN A RETAIL STOCK UPDATE AND YOU STOPPED ME.
```

Now, I'm not doing anything different here, except that my local php script calls the server php script. Everything works fine, except I get undefined variable warnings whenever I try to echo something from my server script. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What you posted for code won't trigger that. Something else is causing this, an include maybe, a function etc. It's just an "echo"; there's no variable assigned to it.

Comment: Post the code that comes before that echo. It's giving the error, then echoing what you are telling it to echo.

Comment: I've found the problem. print_r($$response); It wasn't giving me any errors other than to treat all echoed strings like undeclared variables.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I had this little oversight sitting in my curl handler class;

```
print_r($$response);
```

Echoing a variable variable name caused no errors, other than to treat all echo statements from my script as undefined variables.

Removing the extra '$' fixed the problem, and my script is outputting messages from the other script correctly now.